# FakeItEasy sometimes fails to create a fake when tests are run in parallel

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, fakeiteasy

Unit tests that use FakeItEasy randomly fail when trying to fake a simple intefrace. It occurs in different tests occasionally and is not stable.

Here is a sample interface I need to fake:

```
public interface IJobSuiteFilterApplier
{
     JobSuiteDto FilterJobSuites(JobSuiteDto jobSuiteDto, JobSuiteFilter jobSuiteFilter);
}
```

Here is piece of code that creates the fake and fails sometimes:

```
var jobSuiteFilterApplier = A.Fake<IJobSuiteFilterApplier>(x => x.Strict());
```

Here is the exception details:

```
FakeItEasy.Core.FakeCreationException: 
  Failed to create fake of type "QS.TestShell.Server.ExecutionPlanner.Queries.IExecutionPlannerQueryService".

  Below is a list of reasons for failure per attempted constructor:
    No constructor arguments failed:
      No usable default constructor was found on the type QS.TestShell.Server.ExecutionPlanner.Queries.IExecutionPlannerQueryService.
      An exception was caught during this call. Its message was:
      Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.


    at FakeItEasy.Core.DefaultExceptionThrower.ThrowFailedToGenerateProxyWithResolvedConstructors(Type typeOfFake, String reasonForFailureOfUnspecifiedConstructor, IEnumerable`1 resolvedConstructors)
   at FakeItEasy.Creation.FakeObjectCreator.TryCreateFakeWithDummyArgumentsForConstructor(Type typeOfFake, FakeOptions fakeOptions, IDummyValueCreationSession session, String failReasonForDefaultConstructor, Boolean throwOnFailure)
   at FakeItEasy.Creation.FakeObjectCreator.CreateFake(Type typeOfFake, FakeOptions fakeOptions, IDummyValueCreationSession session, Boolean throwOnFailure)
   at FakeItEasy.Creation.DefaultFakeAndDummyManager.CreateFake(Type typeOfFake, FakeOptions options)
   at FakeItEasy.Creation.DefaultFakeCreatorFacade.CreateFake[T](Action`1 options)
   at FakeItEasy.A.Fake[T](Action`1 options)
```

When I add the following, tests pass, but do it looks strange that I need to add it to all the fake creation:

```
var jobSuiteFilterApplier = A.Fake<IJobSuiteFilterApplier>(x => x.Strict().Synchronized());



public class CallSynchronizer : IInterceptionListener
{
    private static readonly object SynchronizationLock = new object();

    public void OnBeforeCallIntercepted(IFakeObjectCall interceptedCall)
    {
        Monitor.Enter(SynchronizationLock);
    }

    public void OnAfterCallIntercepted(ICompletedFakeObjectCall interceptedCall, IFakeObjectCallRule ruleThatWasApplied)
    {
        Monitor.Exit(SynchronizationLock);
    }
}

public static class MyPersonalFakeExtensions
{
    public static IFakeOptionsBuilder<T> Synchronized<T>(this IFakeOptionsBuilder<T> builder)
    {
        return builder.OnFakeCreated(fake => Fake.GetFakeManager(fake).AddInterceptionListener(new CallSynchronizer()));

    }
}
```

**Update: I am running the tests using ReSharper test runner on developer machine and using mstext.exe on build server. The concurrency settings allow for multiple tests to be run at once.**

Comment: What unit test framework are you using? Are you running the unit tests in parallel or creating fakes on multiple threads? That seems to be an [open issue](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/60).

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning it. I am using FakeItEasy. I am running the tests using ReSharper test runner on developer machine and using mstext.exe on build server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update: FakeItEasy 2.0.0 has drastically improved support for tests run in parallel. Try it.**

as mike z mentioned: FakeItEasy currently doesn't support multi-threaded tests. This is because not all internals are thread-safe, and it's not easy to make it completely thread-safe. There's an open issue, [number 60](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/60), for supporting multi-threaded test execution.

For now the solution you provided is the only way to achieve this, as originally explained here http://hmemcpy.com/2012/12/running-multithreaded-unit-tests-with-fakeiteasy/.

There is no way to globally add an interception listener to all fakes, however you can use the `FakeConfigurator<T>` class to automate this behaviour *per type*, so you could opt to include, for each faked type, a class such as

```
public class SomeTypeSynchronousConfigurator : FakeConfigurator<ISomeType>
{
    public override void ConfigureFake(ISomeType fakeObject)
    {
        Fake.GetFakeManager(fakeObject)
                 .AddInterceptionListener(new CallSynchronizer());
    }
}
```

FakeItEasy will [discover the class](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/wiki/Scanning-for-Extension-Points) and every new fake of (in this case) `ISomeType` will have the synchronizer applied—you can make the fake just like `var fake = A.Fake<ISomeType>();`.

Comment: +1 Philipp for the answer and +1 Blair for the nice embellishment!